# How should I test error message appears in Angular 6

Tags: angular, testing, angular6, angular-test

I am testing the validation of a component, and I can test if it is falsy or not, but I don't know how to test if the error message appears.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control input-lg"
       placeholder="{{ 'validation.attributes.name' | translate }}"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': !f.name.pristine  && f.name.errors }"/>
<div *ngIf="!f.name.pristine && f.name.errors" class="text-primary">
  <div *ngIf="f.name.errors.required">{{ 'validation.required' | translate:{'attribute':'Name'} }}
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my actual test:

```
it(`form should be invalid without name`, async(() => {
  comp.registerForm.controls['name'].setValue('');
  expect(comp.registerForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

How should I test that error message appears ?

EDIT:

I made a debug test with:

```
<div id="test" >qqq</div>
```

I can validate it with:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterComponent);
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
el = de.nativeElement;
const test = el.querySelector('#test');
expect(test.textContent).toContain('qqq'); // This will pass
```

But when I add the condition:

```
*ngIf="!f.name.pristine && f.name.errors"
```

I get:

```
Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

Just to confirm, I have

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

in `beforeEach()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

1. Use a `@ViewChild` element :

   ```
   <div #errorMessage *ngIf="!f.name.pristine && f.name.errors" class="text-primary">

   // In your component
   @ViewChild() errorMessage: ElementRef;
   ```
2. Use a document query selector

   ```
   <div id="errorMessage" *ngIf="!f.name.pristine && f.name.errors" class="text-primary">

   // In your test file
   const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#errorMessage')
   ```

Now in your test you can use either one of those :

```
expect(component.errorMessage.nativeElement).toBeTruthy();
expect(el).toBeTruthy();
```

Both are `HTMLElement`s, so you can access their properties :

```
el.innerHTML
el.className
...
```

Comment: Couldn't make both works :( In the first one, what is component ? if component = fixture.componentInstance; it doesn't work. In the second case, `el` is null. I also tried with # as it is an id and not a class.

Comment: Thank you for the typo, and for the first one, this is in your `XXX.component.ts` file, meaning you declare it in your component class, not in your test file. And feel free to check Angular's testing guide to get the correct syntax (and even other ways, such as `By`) : https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics

Comment: maybe it is null because of the ngIf no ? I mean I checked the docs, and it is pretty much how to use the querySelector, so, maybe, it fails because it is not shown

Comment: As long as you detect changes with `fixture.detectChanges()`, the `*ngIf` should not be an issue. But if you don't, then yes, the condition will be an issue.

Comment: :( I already have fixture.detectChanges() ... I will try to figure out what is wrong with my code

Comment: You can make a [mcve] here so that I can help you with your code  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template

Comment: I edited my question, I have made some test, and it appears that the condition: `*ngIf="f.name.errors.required"` is the problem. I couldn't make the stackblitz work ... :(

Comment: Well give me the link, and I'll tell you what is wrong with it :)

Comment: what I mean is it is not compiling

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro (and while we're at it, try with `f.get('name').hasError('required')` , and `f.hasError('name', 'required')` for your conditions)

Comment: here is stackblitz :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template

Comment: This is the one I gave you, you have to fork it !

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Angular World, is it better ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-z6gtea

Comment: Yeah, perfect ! now reproduce your issue, and I'll make it work